# Connect Remote Task scheduler using c# throws error

Tags: c#

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler.dll

Additional information:

> The request is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070032)

My Code:

```
using (TaskService tasksrvc = new TaskService(@"\\hqbusa1057", "muthuusername", "igatate", "pwd"))
{
    Task task = tasksrvc.FindTask("POC", true); task.Run();
}
```

Comment: Can you please share some source code? We need [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Googling the error code brought up this: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/the-request-is-not-supported-0x80070032-while/7fa954f4-92fc-43d8-8c3b-965b2c1820bb?auth=1 I suspect a problem with the user account used (or not used), though.

Comment: Please **edit** such things into the question instead of comments. (Use the greyish _edit_ link beneath the tags; I did it for you this time.)

Comment: AFAIK you have to specify the name of the computer, not the network path

Comment: i mentioned as hqbusa1057 this only

Comment: You also need to specify the user name in the form of DOMAIN\USER or COMPUTER\USER

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue caused by the **firewall** on the requested computer.

Allow  '*Remote Scheduled Task Management*' in your Windows Firewall to prevent the error when a `new TaskService` is created.

Also, allowing '*Remote Event Log Management*' may be helpful if you want to access task logs (history).